# Cómo usar una variable (local) de un método en otro método?

Tags: java, android

necesito ayuda. Quiero saber cómo puedo implementar una variable (local) de un método (conocido como onDataSet) para usarlo en otro ámbito. Eh intentado creando una variable global, a dicha variable le asigne el valor que toma la variable local, pero por razones que desconozco, el valor que adopta la variable global al salir del método se pierde o es cero o nulo. Pueden ayudarme?

/********* VARIABLES GLOBALES ************/

```
private int pYearFI;
private int pYearFF;
private int pMonthFI;
private int pMonthFF;
private int pDayFI;
private int pDayFF;


DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener selector_fecha_inicio,selector_fecha_fin;

DatePickerDialog dialog_fecha_inicio, dialog_fecha_fin;
```

/******* DENTRO DEL onCreate() ************/

```
    selector_fecha_inicio = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view,  int year, int month,
                               int day) {



                pYearFI = year;
                pMonthFI = month;
                pDayFI = day;



                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, pYearFI);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,pMonthFI);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,pDayFI);


                updateLabelFechaInicio();



            }  /**** Fin del método onDataSet ****/

    }; /*********** Fin del método setOnClickListener ***********/
```

/***** OTRO AMBITO ******/

//AQUI ES DONDE ME INTERESA SABER LO SIGUIENTE: se supone que a la variable llamada (dialog_fecha_fin) le paso como parametros el contexto, el listener, y luego las 3 variables globales de año,mes y dia se supone que deberían tener guardadas o almacenadas el valor seleccionado del método onDataSet, pero no es así, por alguna razón no me guarda esos valores, sus valores se pierden.

```
       dialog_fecha_fin = new DatePickerDialog(this, selector_fecha_fin,
                pYearFI,pMonthFI,pDayFI);


        dialog_fecha_fin.getDatePicker().setMinDate(ConvertirFechaEnMilisegundos(pDayFI,
                pMonthFI,pYearFI));
```

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres cambiar una variable miembro de la clase al recibir el evento entonces debes implementar la interface a nivel de clase:

```
class MiClase implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    private int pYearFI;
    private int pYearFF;
    private int pMonthFI;
    private int pMonthFF;
    private int pDayFI;
    private int pDayFF;

    //...Código de la clase

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view,  int year, int month, int day) {

        this.pYearFI = year;
        this.pMonthFI = month;
        this.pDayFI = day;

        //...más código
    }

}
```